# Drawable.createFromStream loads images at half size

Tags: android, drawable

If I have an image that is 512x512 and I load it using the following code, the IntrinsicWidth and Height values come in as 256x256. Is there a better way to load an image from assets and get the proper width/height?

```
ImageView myImageView = new ImageView(theContext);
try {
        InputStream ims = context.getAssets().open("Splash/clouds.png");
        Drawable d = Drawable.createFromStream(ims, null);
        myImageView.setImageDrawable(d);
        myImageView .setMinimumWidth(d.getIntrinsicWidth());
        myImageView .setMinimumHeight(d.getIntrinsicHeight());
}
catch (IOException e)
{
    Log.e(TAG, "Splash: Load image", e);
}
addView(myImageView);
```

Comment: why don't you move your picture to drawable instead of assets?